# How do I plot a function with different values of a parameter on the same plot in gnuplot 4.4?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a plot with different value of the same parameter (say I have five values) and all on the same plot. How can this be done in gnuplot 4.4? For example consider plotting f(x)= 1/(1+exp(x/a)).

Comment: show us what you tried???

Answer (score 8):

To have several plots in one graph use:

```
f(x,a) = 1/(1+exp(x/a))
plot f(x,1), f(x,2)
```

For a more automated plot command, use `for` iteration:

```
plot for [a=1:5:2] 1/(1+exp(x/a)) title sprintf("a = %d", a)
```

That gives (with version 4.4.4):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. Earlier I was using different names for the function and the parameter and was plotting as following: f(x)=1/(1+exp(x/a1));   g(x)=1/(1+exp(x/a2)); a1=2;a2=5; plot f(x),g(x)  But its a lot of work for a large range of parameters.