# How do I plot an equation with the different values of a sin function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a function in a way similar to the one shown in the figure in the link:

[image]

The equation in which this plot is based on is: y= sin^2θ x /(e^x +1)

I have previously plotted the equation above without the sine function, using the following code:

```
# Generate some data.
x = np.logspace(-1, 3, 100)
y= x * 1/ (np.exp(x) + 1)


plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True) # optionally set a tight x-axis
#adding labels to axis
plt.xlabel('y=E/T')
plt.ylabel('$f_s$')
plt.show()
```

But how can I plot this function with a varying sin function. I have tried applying what was used in the following link but I don't understand the code: [How can I convert numbers to a color scale in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009724/how-can-i-convert-numbers-to-a-color-scale-in-matplotlib)

I am new to python and the code has barely any description in it.

---

I have also tried to apply the method shown in [How do I plot a function with different values of a parameter on the same plot in gnuplot 4.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422723/how-do-i-plot-a-function-with-different-values-of-a-parameter-on-the-same-plot-i) but I keep on getting the same error message, "Invalid synthax pyplate E"

Comment: what is the varying parameter of your function?

Comment: The value of the sin, as the angle varies ,  I obtain different values for sin.

Comment: I posted an answer but have removed it because I may have misunderstood the question. It seems that you want to plot multiple curves on the same axes? But what you quoted is a function only of `x` (y= sin^2 x /(e^x +1)) - did you mean to use something which is a function of both `x` and also some other variable, and then plot that against `x` for a range of values of that other variable?

Comment: I do not understand : your function y(x) depends solely on the x value (the x-axis), how do you expect your sin to have different values for the same x?

Comment: I am sorry, I am miswritten the equation, the sin^2 should be written as sin^2θ . And sin^2θ  presents several values

Comment: Is it x * sin(θ)**2 or sin(2θ) * x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theta = [...] # your values of theta you'd like to plot
x = np.linspace(-1, 3, 100) # Or np.logspace, as you want. You'll have to change the parameters though, if you want to display properly
y = x / (np.exp(x)+1)

for t in theta :
  plt.plot(x, np.sin(2*t)*y, label = 'theta = %s' % t)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result for `theta = [1,2,3]` :

[image: image1]

If you want to display a colormap, you can do this (code taken from [here](https://stackanswers.net/questions/drawing-a-colorbar-aside-a-line-plot-using-matplotlib)) :

```
import matplotlib
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(theta), vmax=np.max(theta))
c_m = matplotlib.cm.cool
s_m = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=c_m, norm=norm)
s_m.set_array([])

for t in theta :
  plt.plot(x, np.sin(2*t)*y, color=s_m.to_rgba(t))

plt.colorbar(s_m)
plt.show()
```

Result :

[image: imageColormap]

Comment: I have tried adding a colour bar, with a colour representing each line, using

c = np.random.random(8) #8 is the number of lines I got

and 

fig.colorbar()

But it says that I only have 8 colours, for 100  points, but I want the values for the different thetas, not x's. Could you help me?